# Tcp/ip using python

Tags: python, tcp

I was trying to run the server and client code. Initially i was running the server code and after few seconds i was running the client code. when i run the client code it runs in the same shell replacing the server code. The server code and client code is given below.

Server code

```
import socket
serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.bind(('localhost', 8089))
serversocket.listen(5) # become a server socket, maximum 5 connections

while True:
    connection, address = serversocket.accept()
    buf = connection.recv(64)
    if len(buf) > 0:
        print buf
        break
```

Client code

```
import socket

clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientsocket.connect(('localhost', 8089))
clientsocket.send('hello')
```

It was showing no error.

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: use `try except` for `socket`  both client and server and for bindings and for `connect` and `send` part in `client` part and show us the feedback here

Comment: How are you running it "in the same shell"?

Comment: and use two shell for `server` and `client` seperatly